# Copy cell (A1) of sheet VN to the first open cell in column F of sheet VL, then A2 to the next open cell in F

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to copy the contents of cell A1 of sheet wsVN to the first open cell in column F of sheet wsVL, then copy A2 to the next open cell in F, then A3 to the next and so on up to A305. Sheet VL has a header row with the first open cell being F2. That's where I'm trying to past A1. Then I have a couple rows with data then another open cell where I'd like to past A2. Then 5 rows of data before the next open cell where A3 should go. Here is as close as I have made it so far:

```
Sub Data_Transfer()
 '
 ' Data_Transfer Macro
 ' Transfers VariableNames Data to the next available row of sheet VariableList.

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim wsVN As Worksheet
    Dim wsVL As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set wsVN = Worksheets("VariableNames")
    Set wsVL = Worksheets("VariationList")


    If Len(wsVL.Range("F1").Value) > 0 Then

        lastRow = wsVL.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row
    Else

        lastRow = 2
    End If

    Set sourceRange = wsVN.Range("A1")
    Set targetRange = wsVL.Range("F" & lastRow).Offset(1, 0)

    sourceRange.Copy
    targetRange.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Hopefully someone will offer some guidance on this. It would be appreciated very much!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, adjusting sheet names to suit.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'source sheet
    For Each r In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Value = r.Value 'destination sheet
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

More on [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells).